# Where is the documentation to upgrade CiviCRM under Drupal 8?

Tags: upgrade, drupal-8, documentation

As of now, there is [official documentation for installing CiviCRM under Drupal 8](https://docs.civicrm.org/installation/en/latest/drupal8/), and there is [official documentation for upgrading CiviCRM under various other CMSs](https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/upgrade/), but I can't find any for upgrading under Drupal 8.

Comment: There was some discussion [in gitlab](https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/drupal/-/issues/115) but it wanders around a bit. There's https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/33945/how-can-i-update-civicrm-installed-with-drupal-8-using-composer but it's not official documentation. Part of the difficulty seems to be doing one thing on one site, like `composer update`, might work on that one site, but then will break another site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Official docs are now available at https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/upgrade/drupal8/